# CSS3 "transform: rotate" and search engines

Tags: html, css, seo, search-engine

Is it search engines friendly to use text using `transform: rotate` with CSS?

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
-moz-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
-ms-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
-o-transform-origin: 75px 75px;
transform-origin: 75px 75px;
```

Comment: It is hard to imagine how positioning/formatting text using CSS would have anything to do with search engine indexing.  Some search engines may look for ways that text is hidden from view, but they really don't care about minor formatting (e.g. rotation).  If you wanted to know for sure, you'd have to discuss this with each search engine development team as none of us know the inner workings of every search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines don't take into account if your rotate an HTML element with CSS. Don't worry about that.